# Oracle Column table Count - Sub-Selection

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I really only want the number of columns in the tables in the SQL query, but somehow i can't get the right result. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
select count(*) from user_tab_columns where table_name='tablename' //works and gives me the number of columns


select 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    NUM_ROWS,
    (select count(*) from user_tab_columns where table_name=TABLE_NAME) as Test
from user_tables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, look at this:

```
where table_name=TABLE_NAME
```

This will always be true, because the table name is the table name.

Here is the query with qualified column names:

```
select 
  table_name, 
  num_rows,
  (select count(*) from user_tab_columns tc where tc.table_name = t.table_name) as test
from user_tables t;
```

Comment: Thanks for help, makes sense. Use alias. haven't developed in a long time. ^^,

Comment: You are welcome :-) The same would of course work without alias names: `where user_tab_columns.table_name = user_tables.table_name`, but alias names are quicker to type and quicker to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could aggregate the whole query:

```
select t.table_name
     , num_rows
     , count(*) as num_columns
from   user_tables t
       join user_tab_columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name
group by t.table_name, t.num_rows
order by 1;
```